# run jquery only on certain screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"), 
                $window    = $(window),
                offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
                topPadding = 15;

            $window.scroll(function() {
                if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    $sidebar.stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                } else {
                    $sidebar.stop().animate({
                        marginTop: 0
                    });
                }
            });
```

I'm using this script to enable sticky sidebar when scrolling thru a page but i want the sidebar to stay in a relative position when the screen size changes from desktop to mobile.

[image]

so when in mobile view, i want it to stay in a fixed relative psoition without the auto scrolling. like this:

[image]

It's not working properly with the script that i wrote. Any advice?

Comment: If you want us to help you with code, you have to show us the code.

Answer (score 2):

To get the width of the window you can do

```
 var w = window.innerWidth;
```

So you can create some sort of conditional before you run the jquery for a certain screen size.

```
if (window.innerWidth > 1200) // dont run jquery
```